# Set a list to method return value but cant use the method

Tags: c#, list, class, methods

I'm trying to set a new List variable to the result of a class' methods return value a bit like this:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // ...stuff...

    // Class initialization
    private Map map = new Map() { Width = 10, Height = 10, TileWidth = 16, TileHeight = 16 };

    // Variable declaration
    List<Vector2> blockPos = new List<Vector2>();
    blockPos = map.generateMap(); // Doesn't work

    Texture2D dirtTex;

    // ...more stuff...
}
```

I figure it doesn't work because it's not inside a method and that I could put it in my Update() method but that runs each frame and I only want to do this once.

Attempting the above code results in 3 errors:

```
'Deep.Game1.blockPos' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
Invalid token '=' in a class, struct, or interface member declaration
'Deep.Game1.map' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

Map class:

```
class Map
{
    // Variable declaration
    public int Width { get; set; } // Width of map in tiles
    public int Height { get; set; } // Height of map in tiles
    public int TileWidth { get; set; }
    public int TileHeight { get; set; }
    Random rnd = new Random();

    // Generate a list of Vector2 positions for blocks
    public List<Vector2> generateMap()
    {
        List<Vector2> blockLocations = new List<Vector2>();

        // For each tile in the map...
        for (int w = 0; w < Width; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < Height; h++)
            {
                // ...decide whether or not to place a tile...
                if (rnd.Next(0, 1) == 1)
                {
                    // ...and if so, add a tile at that location.
                    blockLocations.Add(new Vector2(w * TileWidth, h * TileHeight));
                }
            }
        }

        return blockLocations;
    }
}
```

I tried using constructors, but the code inside it didn't appear to run despite no errors:

```
public void getPos()
{
    blockPos = map.generateMap();
}
```

Comment: are we missing a method or constructor? You can't drop statements just inside the class...

Comment: Can't you just put it in the constructor?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This is the same problem as your last question: you are limited on what you put in a class, and what you put in an executable code block, like a method. You should find a good beginner's C# instruction book/course to help you learn the difference.

Comment: @JLe I tried using a constructor just now, but the code doesn't seem to run - I've added it to the post.

Comment: @Servy Should I delete this then? I've fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by declaring the variable, then setting it to map.generateMap() in the LoadContent() method:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // ...

    // Class initialization
    private Map map = new Map() { Width = 10, Height = 10, TileWidth = 16, TileHeight = 16 };

    // Variable declaration
    List<Vector2> blockPos = new List<Vector2>();

    Texture2D dirtTex;

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        dirtTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("dirt");

        blockPos = map.generateMap();
    }

    // ...
}
```